# How to give for users extra lives for watching Unity Ads?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to give for users extra lives for watching Unity Ads in my small game making in Unity. But I don't know how to do it.

To showing ads I using that:

```
void Awake()
{
    Advertisement.Initialize (gameID, true);
}

public void ShowAd()
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    StartCoroutine(WaitForAd ());
#endif

    if (Advertisement.IsReady ())
        Advertisement.Show ();
}

IEnumerator WaitForAd()
{
    float currentTimeScale = Time.timeScale;
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    yield return null;

    while (Advertisement.isShowing)
        yield return null;

    Time.timeScale = currentTimeScale = 0f;
```

I counting lives in another script using for example

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Meteor")) {
    other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    count_lives = count_lives - 1;
    SetLivesText ();
}
```

but `count_lives = count_lives +1` in script for unity ads not works, btw I using UnityEngine.UI for display the number of lives. Maybe it can be connected with button for start display Ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this supposed to give the player more lives every time he plays the game if he watches the ad?
if that is so I think you should try using player prefs.

in youre "void awake () {}"you should add the following:

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("AdLives");
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("AdLives", 1);
```

and then in youre script that has the lives variable you should add this :

```
void Start (){

   if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Adlives")==1){
      //set the variable that countes the lives to the amount you want for example:
     lives=5;
   }
}
```